# regex for Iraninan ID Serial number

Tags: c#, regex, html, validation

I need a regex expression to match Iranian ID serial number(سریال شماره شناسنامه) which first char is a non-latin letter in range of **ب-ی** or one non-latin word **الف**.

The texts we need to validate should be in a format like:

```
الف/12 123456
ب/25 123456
ج/11 123456
```

ps: the expressions start with a letter. (StackOverflow isn't supporting RTL)

My attempt so far:

```
(\bالف\b|[ب-ی]{1})[\/][0-9]{2}\s{1}[0-9]{6}
```

https://regex101.com/r/FsZFN5/1

Comment: Can you please show what you have so far and how it doesn't meet your requirements? A [mcve] would be a must, along some valid and invalid entries.

Comment: @PJProudhon (\bالف\b|[ب-ی]{1})[\/][0-9]{2}\s{1}[0-9]{6}

Comment: I am not sure how do you want to do matching "non-latin" letter. Are you planning to do a RegEx that matches all latin letters?. If so, the regex would be kinda large, would be `\d{6} \d{2}/[^all_latin_characters]`. IMHO is far more easi matching the characters you want instead

Comment: There is a specific RTL option in .net RegEx. [Check the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_RightToLeft) that would be useful. Consider editing your question and adding a full [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution for non-latin serial number for Iraninans ID:

```
([\u0627][\u0644][\u0641]|[\u0628-\u06CC])[\/][0-9]{2}\s{1}[0-9]{6}
```

https://regex101.com/r/FsZFN5/2

Comment: Looks doing the job! You could remove unnecessary character class signs (surrounding only one char) and quantifiers (`{1}`).

Answer (score 1):

Persian characters are within the Arabic Unicode block, which ranges from U+0600 to U+06FF (which is specified in character class as \u0600-\u06FF).

for English letter below Regex is match:

```
/[0-9]{6}\s[0-9]{2}\/[a-z]{1}/
```

and for supporting Persian letter, only replace `a-z` with `\u0600-\u06FF`:

```
/[0-9]{6}\s[0-9]{2}\/[\u0600-\u06FF]{1}/
```

Comment: Not into serial numbers but, zeroes are not allowed?. This is a bug: `[\u0600-\u06FF]{1}` should be `[\u0600-\u06FF]+`

Comment: please consider string started with letter not number

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad "consider string started with letter not number". Well, the regex matches what you say it should match, consider improving your question with more examples.

Answer (score 0):

new series like : الف/12 123456

{char} {2 digit} / {6 digit}

solution:

```
 [\u0600-\u06FF]{1,3}[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{6}
```